# How do I solve 404 Flask error in python?

Tags: python, flask

I'm dealing with text files and new in learning API building with Flask, I wanted to have data extraction from text files, and would like to generate the JSON output, but unfortunately, i keep getting this 404 page when I load the API URL can anyone help me with this 
thanks in advance

Here's the code Below

```py
import re
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import json

app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/flask_resume',methods =["POST"])
def flask_resume():
    file = request.files['file']

    files = file.read()
    return files

    #extracting workexperience and summary titles
    with open(files,'r', encoding='latin-1')as file1:
        with open('Details.txt','r',encoding='latin-1' )as file2:
            same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

    same.discard('\n')
    words_list = []

    for line in same:
        words_list.append(line)

    words_list = list(map(str.strip,words_list))
    print ('words_list', words_list)

    #extracting other titles
    with open(files,'r', encoding='latin-1')as file3:
        with open('other_details.txt','r',encoding='latin-1' )as file4:
            same1 = set(file3).intersection(file4)

    same1.discard('\n')
    words_extract = []

    for f in same1:
        words_extract.append(f)

    words_extract = list(map(str.strip,words_extract))
    print ('words_extract', words_extract)

    #function to replace extracted titles        
    def multiwordReplace(text, wordDic):
        rc = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, wordDic)))
        def translate(match):
            return wordDic[match.group(0)]
        return rc.sub(translate, text)


    str1 = open(files,'r', encoding='latin-1')
    str1 = str1.read()

    wordDic1 = dict((k,'Summary') for k in words_list)
    wordDic2 = dict((k,'xyz') for k in words_extract)
    wordDic = dict(wordDic1, **wordDic2)
    print(wordDic)

    with open ('set.txt','w', encoding='latin-1') as infile:
        str2 = multiwordReplace(str1,wordDic)
        infile.write(str2)

    #extracting summary paragraphs
    with open("set.txt", encoding='latin-1')as infile,open("fgl.txt",'w', encoding='latin-1')as outfile:
        copy = False
        for word in words_extract:
            for line in infile:
                if line.strip() == "Summary":
                    copy = True

                elif line.strip() == "xyz":
                    copy = False
                elif copy:
                    outfile.write(line)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And the output screen is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7ENy.png)

Comment: Do you know about HTTP methods (get, post, etc..)? Your API is only open for the POST method but your calling for GET.

Comment: @Taegyung I'm new to python and Flask, could you please explain me in detail, the thing is I want to post the output to other factors after complete executing

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your root path "/" in URL - http://127.0.0.1:5000/

 Add below code just above `if __name__ == "__main__":`

`@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "hello"`

If you want `flask_resume` to be your landing page then it should be `'/'` instead of `'/flask_resume'` without any methods.

Full code -

````
import re
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import json

app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/flask_resume',methods =["POST"])
def flask_resume():
    file = request.files['file']

    files = file.read()
    return files

    #extracting workexperience and summary titles
    with open(files,'r', encoding='latin-1')as file1:
        with open('Details.txt','r',encoding='latin-1' )as file2:
            same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

    same.discard('\n')
    words_list = []

    for line in same:
        words_list.append(line)

    words_list = list(map(str.strip,words_list))
    print ('words_list', words_list)

    #extracting other titles
    with open(files,'r', encoding='latin-1')as file3:
        with open('other_details.txt','r',encoding='latin-1' )as file4:
            same1 = set(file3).intersection(file4)

    same1.discard('\n')
    words_extract = []

    for f in same1:
        words_extract.append(f)

    words_extract = list(map(str.strip,words_extract))
    print ('words_extract', words_extract)

    #function to replace extracted titles        
    def multiwordReplace(text, wordDic):
        rc = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, wordDic)))
        def translate(match):
            return wordDic[match.group(0)]
        return rc.sub(translate, text)


    str1 = open(files,'r', encoding='latin-1')
    str1 = str1.read()

    wordDic1 = dict((k,'Summary') for k in words_list)
    wordDic2 = dict((k,'xyz') for k in words_extract)
    wordDic = dict(wordDic1, **wordDic2)
    print(wordDic)

    with open ('set.txt','w', encoding='latin-1') as infile:
        str2 = multiwordReplace(str1,wordDic)
        infile.write(str2)

    #extracting summary paragraphs
    with open("set.txt", encoding='latin-1')as infile,open("fgl.txt",'w', encoding='latin-1')as outfile:
        copy = False
        for word in words_extract:
            for line in infile:
                if line.strip() == "Summary":
                    copy = True

                elif line.strip() == "xyz":
                    copy = False
                elif copy:
                    outfile.write(line)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "hello"

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run(debug=True)```
````

Comment: werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'files'

Comment: this is the output once i did this @Khilesh Chauhan

Comment: Would it be possible to paste screenshot of code and your output ?